# How does this for loops works?

Tags: c++, loops

can someone explain how the highest and lowest works in the if statement?
and what happen when we use cin.sync()?
it works but i dont know how it works.

````
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
 string name, p1, p2;
 int n;
 double salary, sales, income, commission, highest, lowest;
 highest=0;
 lowest=9999999;
 for(n=1; n<=2; n++)
{
    cout<<"Enter your name?"<<endl;
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Enter "<<name<<" salary:"<<endl;
    cin>>salary;
    cout<<"Enter "<<name<<" total price of car sold"<<endl;
    cin>>sales;
    cin.sync();
    commission=sales*0.03;
    income=commission+salary;
    cout<<name<<" income is RM"<<income<<endl;
    if(income>highest){
        highest=income;
        p1=name;
    }
    if(income< lowest){
        lowest=income;
        p2=name;
    }
 }
 cout<<"Highest income is salesman named "<<p1<<endl;
 cout<<"Lowest income is salesman named "<<p2<<endl;
  
}```
````

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/14215102)

Comment: How would you find out what `cin.sync()` does if you wanted to find out for yourself? Is it documented somewhere? The variables are named highest and lowest. How would you go about finding the highest and lowest number in a sequence?

Comment: The `cin.sync()` looks like an incantation someone added because they heard a rumour about how it provides some unspecified benefit.

Comment: im sorry dratenik but wherever i search about the `cin.sync()` i did not understand the function

Comment: @XenonZox It's a very obscure function, and it's unlikely that you're ever going to be in a situation where it's useful.

Comment: @molbdnilo so what does it actually do to the code?

Comment: In this code, it does nothing.

Comment: so if i remove it then there will be no error right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225704/discussion-between-xenon-zox-and-molbdnilo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop will run only two times. Once for n=1, and then for n=2.

From what I understand we want to get the highest value. So we initialize it with the min value that is 0. Next whatever value salary has for the first time will be set as highest.
After this (from the second time) only the value of the highest will change only if(income>highest). The var highest will store the max value.

Similarly, it works for the lowest. We initialize the lowest with a very high value so that any first value would lower than it.